# Bootstrap dropdown click, uncollapse div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty new to HTML, CSS, JS, Bootstrap and JQuery and I have a problem I have been unable to find the solution to.

I have a simple dropdown as such:

```
<div id="testform" class="container">
    <form action="action_page.php">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Study</legend>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button id="study" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Study
                <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" data-value="action-1">Digital Media Engineering</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

And I have a div that is collapsed on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".focus_hide").addClass("collapse");
});
```

What I want to do is to get this div to show when clicking on my dropdown value (In this case digital media engineering). However I want to add multiple solutions, so based on what you choose in the dropdown I want to show a div that matches this.. I plan on having multiple divs matching the choices in the dropdown and then only showing the div that matches the choise. The div I want to show when selecting "digital media engineering" is this:

```
<div class="focus_hide" id="dme">
    <form action="action_page.php">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Focus Area</legend>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button id="study" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Focus
                <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Social media and apps</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">UX User experience</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Data science</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Computer games</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Computer graphics</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

What I am missing is the JS code to "un-collapse" the div with id="dme"..

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet will give you a general idea of what you are needing to do. Please note changes where made to the below to make it work. You will have to find those changes and how they achieve your desired result.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".focus_hide").hide();

  $(".show_dme").click(function() {
    $(".focus_hide").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testform" class="container">
  <form action="action_page.php">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Study</legend>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button id="study" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Study
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#" class="show_dme" data-value="action-1">Digital Media Engineering</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="focus_hide" id="dme">
  <form action="action_page.php">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Focus Area</legend>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button id="study" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Focus
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Social media and apps</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">UX User experience</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Data science</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Computer games</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Computer graphics</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like what I was trying to do. 

I will test it as soon as I get home! In the example however you're using "hide()" and "show()". Do you know if it is possible to do with "collapse()"?

Comment: @Zeliax yes you can use Jquery collapse I did not include it in the example because it is a 3rd party library.